# Capture time a record was created in Marketing Cloud synced data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, sync

We are syncing a number of objects from SF into MC.  I would like to capture the date/time the record was actually created in Marketing Cloud.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Comment: For what purpose? Changes are detailed in the activity log in the object configuration in Contact Builder, but not specifically when it was created in SFMC.  Rows are added/deleted/changed on the interval you specify.